# Running a Keycloak Cluster in GKE

Tags: keycloak, google-kubernetes-engine

Im trying to get KeyCloak 20.0.1 running as a cluster in GKE.

The deployment is not a problem, but figuring out how the cluster cache is working is a pain.

The deployment is running using a Cloud SQL (Mysql 5.7) instance.

The question is, should I use
cache-stack=kubernetes or cache-stack=google, or can I use UDP og TCP?

If I should use the kubernets cache stack, how do I configure the headless-service thing needed?

Hopefully someone is already running Keycloak as a cluster in GKE and are willing to share some knowledge and maybe the yaml files for the deployment.

I have tried to configure all different cache-stack options, the result is the following in the logs:
[org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) keycloak: no members discovered after 2008 ms: creating cluster as coordinator
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

The parameter for the jGroup described in https://www.keycloak.org/server/caching, -Djgroups.dns.query=, need to be set to to the service name for the clusterIP in the deployment yml file. In my case *${GKE_NAME}-jgroups-ping*

Here is the yml files and Docerfile for doing cluster deployment of Keycloak in GKE
Im using bitbucket pipeline.

**deployment.yml**

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: ${GKE_NAME}
  name: ${GKE_NAME}
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ${GKE_NAME}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ${GKE_NAME}
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: $IMAGE_NAME
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args: ["start", "--optimized","-Djgroups.dns.query=${GKE_NAME}-jgroups-ping"]
        name: ${GKE_NAME}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 4444
        - containerPort: 8888
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: ${GKE_NAME}
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /realms/master
            port: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: ${GKE_NAME}
  name: ${GKE_NAME}-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: ${GKE_NAME}
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: ${GKE_NAME}
  name: ${GKE_NAME}-jgroups-ping
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 4444
      name: ping
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 4444
  selector:
    app: ${GKE_NAME}
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: ${GKE_NAME}
  namespace: default
spec:
  domains:
    - $DOMAIN
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "${GKE_NAME}"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "${GKE_STATIC_IP_NAME}"
  name: ${GKE_NAME}-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: ${GKE_NAME}-service
      port: 
        number: 8080
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Dockerfile
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_DB=mysql
ENV KC_CACHE=ispn
ENV KC_CACHE_STACK=kubernetes
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
# Replace with your own certificate if needed
RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore conf/server.keystore
RUN bin/kc.sh build
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```